# Google StreetView iOS returns error code 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Why the Streetview [GSMPanoramaView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview) returns for **some** (but very often) locations error code 0. That means the view is not loaded and I see the loader with gray background forever.

Here is the output of NSError:

> Error Domain=com.google.maps.GMSPanoramaService Code=0 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (com.google.maps.GMSPanoramaService error 0.)"

From

```
-(void)panoramaView:(GMSPanoramaView *)view error:(NSError *)error onMoveNearCoordinate:
```

Delegate method.

It is important to say, that most of these not functional locations actually **do have** google streetview, because for example following api works for them.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=LAT,LONG&fov=90&heading=180&pitch=0&sensor=false

BTW this is one of locations which doesnt work via iOS SDK:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=47.798937,18.722434&fov=90&heading=180&pitch=0&sensor=false

As I say, it is not problem of some bad Google API key or something, because some locations works. But many of them (most/many of them) does not! (So it is useless)

It does not even work if I try to call it for these problematic locations reapeatedly. I have same problem on two phones with different systems (iOS8,9). So it is not matter of phone etc.

I install the panorama view from viewDidLoad method.

I also tried to change this

```
 [panoView moveNearCoordinate:loc];
```

to this

```
 [panoView moveNearCoordinate:loc radius:30];
```

but it didnt help.

**Edit**: Now I see many of them doesnt work even via that web api, but still I think the streetview is in fact available around that place.

Here is sample of not functional location.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=49.9986,13.6388&fov=90&heading=180&pitch=0&sensor=false

Comment: you got the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: in the middle of 2020, same issue is happening here..I have been going into the rabbit hole, not knowing why...